# A quote by Halmos - where can I find it?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

The quote "A good stock of examples, as large as possible, is indispensable for a thorough understanding of any concept, and when I want to learn something new, I make it my first job to build one", is attributed to Paul Halmos.

Does anyone know where it's written? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See P.Halmos, [I Want to be a Mathematician: An Automathography (Springer, 1985)](https://books.google.it/books?id=7VblBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA63), page 63:

> A good **stock** of examples...

Comment: Misquote in question ("stack" instead of "stock") now corrected.